# Relative variable importance for Boosting

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, predictive-models, cart, boosting

I'm looking for an explanation of how relative variable importance is computed in Gradient Boosted Trees that is not overly general/simplistic like:

*The measures are based on the number of times a variable is selected for splitting, weighted by the squared improvement to the model as a result of each split, and averaged over all trees*. [[Elith et al. 2008, A working guide to boosted regression trees](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2656.2008.01390.x/full)]

And that is less abstract than:

$\hat{I_{j}^2}(T)=\sum\limits_{t=1}^{J-1} \hat{i_{t}^2} 1(v_{t}=j)$

*Where the summation is over the nonterminal nodes $t$ of the $J$-terminal node
tree $T$, $v_{t}$ is the splitting variable associated with node $t$, and $\hat{i_{t}^2}$ is the corresponding empirical improvement in squared error as a result of the split, defined as $i^2(R_{l},R_{r})=\frac{w_{l}w_{r}}{w_{l}+w_{r}}(\bar{y_{l}}-\bar{y_{r}})^2$, where $\bar{y_{l}}, \bar{y_{r}}$ are the left and right daughter response means respectively, and $w_{l}, w_{r}$ are the corresponding sums of the weights.* [[Friedman 2001, Greedy function approximation: a gradient boosting machine](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1013203451)]

Finally, I did not find [the Elements of Statistical Learning (Hastie et al. 2008)](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf) to be a very helpful read here, as the relevant section (10.13.1 page 367) tastes very similar to the second reference above (which might be explained by the fact that Friedman is a co-author of the book).

PS: I know relative variable importance measures are given by the [summary.gbm](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gbm/docs/summary.gbm) in the gbm R package. I tried to explore the source code, but I can't seem to find where the actual computation takes place.

Brownie points: I'm wondering how to get these [plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637145/gradient-boosting-in-r-get-variable-importance-separately-for-each-class) in R.

Comment: I just added a new answer to the linked question about how to plot variable importance by class which may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/51952918/3277050

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I'll use the [sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn) code, as it is generally much cleaner than the `R` code.

Here's the implementation of the feature_importances property of the [GradientBoostingClassifier](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py) (I removed some lines of code that get in the way of the conceptual stuff)

```
def feature_importances_(self):
    total_sum = np.zeros((self.n_features, ), dtype=np.float64)
    for stage in self.estimators_:
        stage_sum = sum(tree.feature_importances_
                        for tree in stage) / len(stage)
        total_sum += stage_sum

    importances = total_sum / len(self.estimators_)
    return importances
```

This is pretty easy to understand.  `self.estimators_` is an array containing the individual trees in the booster, so the for loop is iterating over the individual trees. There's one hickup with the

```
stage_sum = sum(tree.feature_importances_
                for tree in stage) / len(stage)
```

this is taking care of the non-binary response case.  Here we fit multiple trees in each stage in a one-vs-all way.  Its simplest conceptually to focus on the binary case, where the sum has one summand, and this is just `tree.feature_importances_`.  So in the binary case, we can rewrite this all as

```
def feature_importances_(self):
    total_sum = np.zeros((self.n_features, ), dtype=np.float64)
    for tree in self.estimators_:
        total_sum += tree.feature_importances_ 
    importances = total_sum / len(self.estimators_)
    return importances
```

So, in words, *sum up the feature importances of the individual trees, then divide by the total number of trees*.  It remains to see how to calculate the feature importances for a single tree.

The importance calculation of a tree is implemented at the [cython level](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx), but it's still followable.  Here's a cleaned up version of the code

```
cpdef compute_feature_importances(self, normalize=True):
    """Computes the importance of each feature (aka variable)."""

    while node != end_node:
        if node.left_child != _TREE_LEAF:
            # ... and node.right_child != _TREE_LEAF:
            left = &nodes[node.left_child]
            right = &nodes[node.right_child]

            importance_data[node.feature] += (
                node.weighted_n_node_samples * node.impurity -
                left.weighted_n_node_samples * left.impurity -
                right.weighted_n_node_samples * right.impurity)
        node += 1

    importances /= nodes[0].weighted_n_node_samples

    return importances
```

This is pretty simple.  Iterate through the nodes of the tree.  As long as you are not at a leaf node, calculate the weighted reduction in node purity from the split at this node, and attribute it to the feature that was split on

```
importance_data[node.feature] += (
    node.weighted_n_node_samples * node.impurity -
    left.weighted_n_node_samples * left.impurity -
    right.weighted_n_node_samples * right.impurity)
```

Then, when done, divide it all by the total weight of the data (in most cases, the number of observations)

```
importances /= nodes[0].weighted_n_node_samples
```

It's worth recalling that the [impurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning#Gini_impurity) is a common name for the metric to use when determining what split to make when growing a tree.  In that light, we are simply summing up how much splitting on each feature allowed us to reduce the impurity across all the splits in the tree.

In the context of gradient boosting, these trees are always regression trees (minimize squared error greedily) fit to the gradient of the loss function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very detailed answer. Let me some time to carefully go through it before I accept it.

Comment: While it seems that various impurity criteria can be used, the Gini index was not the criterion used by Friedman. As mentioned in my question and line 878 of your third link, Friedman used the *mean squared error impurity criterion with improvement score*. If you could update this section of your answer, that would be great. And yes, your're right, it seems that the weights are indeed the number of observations.

Comment: or maybe it would make your answer even better to keep both the parts about the Gini index and Friedman's original criterion, stressing that the first is used for classification and the second for regression?

Comment: Antoine,   thanks for this update.  It is really helpful to know that the mean squared error is the improvement criteria used for the regression trees.   It was not obvious how that would be used for classification.       However, even in gradient boosting for classification, I think that regression trees are still being used, as opposed to classification trees.   At least in python, the regression analysis is being done on the current error at each boosting stage.

Comment: You guys are correct about regression trees.

Comment: I just edited to make that point more clear.

Comment: Hey @matthew-drury. Sorry for recovering an old topic but I tried to work through the code with an example and have a question.
Let's assume that we have a data set with 4 examples: {1, 2, 3, 3}. We split it in a tree to two leaves: L={1, 2}, R={3,3}
The Gini Impurity of the parent node is:
1-2*[(0,25)^2]-2*(0,5)^2=0,625;
of the left node:
1-2*(0,5)^2=0,5
while for the right node it is equal to 0. The reduction of Gini Impurity weighted by the number of observations in each node is
0,625*4-0,5*2-0*2 = 1,5
Dividing it all by the number of observations:
1,5/4=0,375

Comment: However, scikit-learn for only one split provides feature importance equal to 1. A reproducible example:
    `from sklearn.datasets import load_iris`
    `from sklearn import tree`
    `clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 1)`
    `iris = load_iris()`
    `clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)`
    `clf.feature_importances_`

`array([ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.])`

I guess I'm missing something in my calculation but I cannot detect an error. Can you see what is missing in my computation?

Comment: how in this formula do we consider that the first boosted tree is more important than the 100 boosted tree? shouldn't be a weight for the tree as well? or does that come into play because the weights of the samples themselves become smaller when we progress thru the boosted trees?

Comment: @ihadanny I've had that thought as well.  I don't think this standard method deals with that issue at all.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Do you think that if a variable appears to be important (in the variable importance plot) for another variable, then the second one would appear to be important for the first one as well ? Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63119574/is-variable-importance-a-two-way-route