# How is gain computed in XGBoost regressor?

Tags: regression, cart, boosting

When you train your XGBoost regression model, you can obtain feature importances by using:

```
model.get_score(importance_type="gain")
```

Although I tried to reconstruct the value and have done some research on it, I am still struggling to figure out, **how gain is computed in XGBoost?**

It is partially explained here: [Relative variable importance for Boosting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162162/relative-variable-importance-for-boosting)

But this is focused on classification. And even though there is a link saying that `squared error with Friedman's improvement score` is used, I have not reached the same numbers.

Comment: I need to edit that answer of mine. In fact, regression trees are always used in boosting. So it is subtly incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

After all it seems that **gain** is computed in quite complicated manner and it's explanation can be found at https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/model.html at the bottom of the page.

Gain is a metric defined by XGBoost and it also involves evaluation of the structure of the tree.

Due to the complexity of the explanation, it is not copied in here.